# Независимое движение объекта (Python + curses + threading)

Tags: python, ncurses, потоки-данных

На экране имеются два объекта. Одним из них управляет игрок (#). Другой движется сам, независимо от действий игрока (*). Написал нечто вроде такого (часть программы):

```
heigh = 1
width = 1
stdscr.addstr(heigh, width, '#')

def move_ball(max_width):
    global ball_heigh, ball_width
    for i in xrange(max_width):
        stdscr.addstr(ball_heigh, ball_width+i, '*')
        stdscr.refresh()
        curses.napms(100) # временная задержка
        stdscr.addstr(ball_heigh, ball_width+i, ' ')

ball_heigh = 4
ball_width = 1
stdscr.addstr(ball_heigh, ball_width, '*')

max_width = 20
thread_ball = threading.Thread(target=move_ball(max_width))
thread_ball.start()

while True:
    ch = stdscr.getch()
    if ch == curses.KEY_RIGHT:
        stdscr.addstr(heigh, width, ' ')
        width += 1
        stdscr.addstr(heigh, width, '#')
        stdscr.refresh()
```

Но почему-то при движении ball изменение местоположения игрока на экране не происходит, а меняется только после окончания движения. Как правильно сделать подобное?

Answer (score 1):

```
- thread_ball = threading.Thread(target=move_ball(max_width))
+ thread_ball = threading.Thread(target=move_ball, args=[max_width])
```

Answer (score 0):

Правильнее всего такое делать на фреймворке, заточенном под это дело. Если хотите понять как это всё работает на низких уровнях, советую [pygame](http://www.pygame.org/). Если не хотите заморачиваться, можете взять [kivy](http://kivy.org/).

А велосипеды не нужны.

Comment: Как `pygame` так и `kivy` создают GUI. `curses` используется для создания TUI (csysdig, htop, iftop, iotop, nethogs, ncdu, glances).